# Reindex data stuck on Processing

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, reindex, ssh

I reindexed all data successfully with SSH `php -f indexer.php reindexall`:

```
Product Attributes index was rebuilt successfully
Product Prices index was rebuilt successfully
Catalog URL Rewrites index was rebuilt successfully
Product Flat Data index was rebuilt successfully
Category Flat Data index was rebuilt successfully
Category Products index was rebuilt successfully
Catalog Search Index index was rebuilt successfully
Stock Status index was rebuilt successfully
```

But after when i go to `Magento admin > System > Index Management` all *Status* are still on `Processing`, and i can't reindex? In Magento admin the date (Updated at) is **Sep 5, 2015.**. But if i look in `/var/locks/` folder the dates from the *lock-files* are from today **Dec 15, 2015.**

Somewhere it's stuck. What do i have to do?

Comment: what happens when you reindex via admin? Did you tried removing all var/lock files? If not, please remove and reindex via admin.

Comment: Yes i tried that. I removed all `var/locks` files and then i tried to reindex but still i get same error (from the first indexed data): `Category Flat Data Index process is working now. Please try run this process later.`

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it programmatically. This way:

```
$indexCollection = Mage::getModel('index/process')->getCollection();
    foreach ($indexCollection as $index) {
      $index->reindexAll();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the files owner, it could be that php from command line is running by different user than when running php through Apache or similar. So after reindexing is done via command line, the index lock file is can be only accessed via php cli and when you go to Index Management it cannot perform lock and therefore thinks that reindexing in progress.